# Why typescript is not throwing error even if an unwanted property is present in the interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Consider the following code block

```
interface Store {
    loading: boolean;
}

interface StoreMethod {
    (s: Store): Store;
}

export const createStore: StoreMethod = (store) => {
    return { ...store, working: false };
}


export const loadStore: StoreMethod = (store) => {
    return { loading: true, working: false };
}
```

I am expecting typescript to throw an error because in the return object is supposed to be `Store` which does not have property `working`. Am I missing something?

You can check the code in playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Store%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loading%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20StoreMethod%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(s%3A%20Store)%3A%20Store%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20createStore%3A%20StoreMethod%20%3D%20(store)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20...store%2C%20working%3A%20false%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20loadStore%3A%20StoreMethod%20%3D%20(store)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20loading%3A%20true%2C%20working%3Afalse%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D).

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand that typescript **transpiles** your code to plain javascript which has no concept of interfaces.

In typescript type `A` is compatible with type `B` if `A` has all of the properties that `B` does **but A does not have to have the exact number of properties that B has**, `A` **has** to **at least** have those properties that `B` does, aka, `A` could contain other properties which are not present in `B`. So this function

```
export const loadStore: StoreMethod = (store) => {
    return { loading: true, working: false };
}
```

The returned object clearly has a propert called `loading` which satifies the *contract* your `Store` imposes, so the returned object is considered compatible to `Store`, if you remove the `loading` property from the returned object, typescript will complain.

Interface in typescript is a design artifact, it is not present at runtime.

Comment: So what should I do if I want the exact same properties?

Comment: Then you just have to modify your code to so, there is no way to enforce it at transpilation time